# Unable to Edit link in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How come no longer able to click on "change source" button under “edit link"?

Is there any way for my excel to be sheet protected and workbook protected  while still  enabling other users to use the "change source" button ?

Comment: Without sufficient information it's difficult to find the reason,, better share the Workbook on cloud or Drop box to test the issue.

Comment: Where did you open the file? What kind of data source are you using now?